# <p> tag inside my <div> won't display text in one line?

Tags: html, css

I am building a website and I want to have a logo (as a link) in the top left, then the title of my page ("Danny Steveson"), floating to the right of the image. I also want the text("Danny Steveson") to align itself with the bottom of the . Everything works except it causes my "text" for the page title to automatically have a line break. I want ("Danny Steveson") to appear as one line.

Please Help Me!

Here is my HTML:

```css
 html   {
    color: white;
    }
 body   {
    background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
 #container  {
    background-color: rgb(67, 67, 67);
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity:0.88;
    }
 #header  {
    max-width: 100%;
    }
 #logo   {
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    }
 #top_info   {
    float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 106px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    }
 #topHeaderText
    {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    }
 #topNavBar  {
    clear: both;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    border-bottom: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.7;
         }
 #topNavBar ul
    {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 12px 0;
    }
 #topNavBar li
    {
    display: inline;
    }
 #topNavBar li a
    {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    }
 #topNavBar a:hover
    {
    color: DarkKhaki;
    }
 #content_area
    {
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.7;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    }
 #content_header
    {
    color: DarkKhaki;
    text-align: center;
    }
 #content_Text
    {
    text-align: center;
    }
 #footer     {
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.7;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-left: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    border-top: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    border-right: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    }
 #footer p   {
    font-size: .7em;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Danny Steveson Portfolio</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DannyStevesonPortfolio.css" />
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="titleLogo.png" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Container -->
 <div id="container">
<!-- Header -->
     <div id="header">
         <div id="logo">
             <a href="default.html" title="Home Page">
     <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
     </a>
            </div>
            <div id="top_info">
                 <span id="topHeaderText">Danny Steveson</span>
            </div>
            <div id="topNavBar">
             <ul>
       <li><a href="webDesign.html">Web Design</a></li>
       <li><a href="gameDesign.html">Game Design</a></li>
     <li><a href="databases.html">Databases</a></li>
     <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
<!-- Content Area -->        
        <div id="content_area">
            <div id="content_header">
             <h1>Welcome to my portfolio!</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content_Text">
              <p>
      My Name is Danny Steveson. I have recently earned a Bachelor's Degree<br />
      of Computer Science with a G.P.A. of 3.76. I am an extremely hard-working<br />
      and driven individual that is currently seeking new opportunities.<br /> 
      <br />
      I am passionate about programming with HTML, HTML5, XHTML, CSS, and JavaScript.<br />
      I have a basic understanding of relational databases and enjoy programming with<br />
      SQL as well. I also have some knowledge of PHP, .NET, Action Scripting and C#.<br />
      <br />
      In addition to programming, I have a background in computer 3-D/2-D art<br />
      applications and concepts. 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        
<!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer">
         <p>Created by: Danny Steveson 2015</p>
        </div>
<!-- END Container -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you remove the `float: left` from `#top_info` your name appears in one line without any noticeable effect on the rest of your layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative to removing the float, you can force text to not wrap by using the 'white-space: nowrap;' rule

```
#topHeaderText {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This works great as well. This way my <div> tags stay lined up. Thank you very much.

Comment: feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it solves your problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float:left` from `#top_info` class.

```css
html   {
    color: white;
    }
 body   {
    background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
 #container  {
    background-color: rgb(67, 67, 67);
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity:0.88;
    }
 #header  {
    max-width: 100%;
    }
 #logo   {
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    }
 #top_info   {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 106px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    }
 #topHeaderText
    {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    }
 #topNavBar  {
    clear: both;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    border-bottom: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.7;
         }
 #topNavBar ul
    {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 12px 0;
    }
 #topNavBar li
    {
    display: inline;
    }
 #topNavBar li a
    {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px;
    }
 #topNavBar a:hover
    {
    color: DarkKhaki;
    }
 #content_area
    {
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.7;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    }
 #content_header
    {
    color: DarkKhaki;
    text-align: center;
    }
 #content_Text
    {
    text-align: center;
    }
 #footer     {
    background-color: black;
    opacity:0.7;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-left: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    border-top: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    border-right: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
    }
 #footer p   {
    font-size: .7em;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Danny Steveson Portfolio</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DannyStevesonPortfolio.css" />
 <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="titleLogo.png" />
</head>

<body>
<!-- Container -->
 <div id="container">
<!-- Header -->
     <div id="header">
         <div id="logo">
             <a href="default.html" title="Home Page">
     <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
     </a>
            </div>
            <div id="top_info">
                 <span id="topHeaderText">Danny Steveson</span>
            </div>
            <div id="topNavBar">
             <ul>
       <li><a href="webDesign.html">Web Design</a></li>
       <li><a href="gameDesign.html">Game Design</a></li>
     <li><a href="databases.html">Databases</a></li>
     <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
<!-- Content Area -->        
        <div id="content_area">
            <div id="content_header">
             <h1>Welcome to my portfolio!</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="content_Text">
              <p>
      My Name is Danny Steveson. I have recently earned a Bachelor's Degree<br />
      of Computer Science with a G.P.A. of 3.76. I am an extremely hard-working<br />
      and driven individual that is currently seeking new opportunities.<br /> 
      <br />
      I am passionate about programming with HTML, HTML5, XHTML, CSS, and JavaScript.<br />
      I have a basic understanding of relational databases and enjoy programming with<br />
      SQL as well. I also have some knowledge of PHP, .NET, Action Scripting and C#.<br />
      <br />
      In addition to programming, I have a background in computer 3-D/2-D art<br />
      applications and concepts. 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        
<!-- Footer -->
        <div id="footer">
         <p>Created by: Danny Steveson 2015</p>
        </div>
<!-- END Container -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That works great! Thank you very much for the immediate response as well. I am new to this site so I am not quite sure on how to give YOU credit besides just voting on how "useful" the answer was. Please let me know if there is anything I can do and thank you again.